# Full Justification in ttfamily

Tags: typewriter

Here is my MWE. I wish for text with full justification, that is
the text lines up perfectly with the right margin. I can not 
find a simple answer to this, Please help.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25 in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25 in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6 in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{5.75 in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.75 in}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5 in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1 in}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard typewriter fonts inhibit hyphenation and have fixed width interword spacing, because they're commonly used for listings where alignment is important.

You can load the fonts with different settings, though.

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25 in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25 in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6 in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5 in}
\setlength{\textheight}{5.75 in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.75 in}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5 in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1 in}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareFontFamily{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{%
  \hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar
  \fontdimen2\font=0.33333em
  \fontdimen3\font=0.16667em
  \fontdimen4\font=0.11111em
  \fontdimen7\font=0.11111em
}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you don't want hyphenation, replace `\defaulthyphenchar` by `-1`.

[image]

Comment: This worked, but the other styles, bfseries, mdseries, itshape, were all displayed as typewriter. Fran's answer worker better for me.

Comment: @ScotParker Just localize the `\ttfamily` declaration issuing inside a group (or environment). Fran's answer won't work on different font sizes than the normal one.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\fontdimen3\font=1ex % interword stretch
\fontdimen4\font=1ex % interword shrink
\fontdimen7\font=1ex % extra space
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

or ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\fontdimen7\font=2pt % extra space
\fontdimen3\font=1em % interword stretch
\fontdimen4\font=1em % interword shrink

\begin{document}
\justify \lipsum
\end{document}
```